# Do event handler function will leads to memory leak, which is referring to an outer scope element

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Do event handler function will leads to memory leak, which is having element in outer scope

Ex:

```
function makeLableEditable(btnItem)
{
   x.addDOMListener(btnItem.firstChild, 'onmousedown', function(){
        btnItem.parentElement.setAttribute('draggable', false);
    });
    x.addDOMListener(btnItem.firstChild, 'onmouseup', function(){
        btnItem.parentElement.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    });         
}
```

Do the above results in memory leak, as the event handler function referes to the outerscope html object (btnItem). Not reffering to the outerscope variable will solve the problem? (I still doubt)

Please help me to understand it.

Comment: Side note: It's "label", not "lable". :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do the above results in memory leak, as the event handler function referes to the outerscope html object (btnItem).

It's not a *leak*, but yes, it keeps the "execution context" of the call to `makeLableEditable` in memory, and if `btnItem` refers to something that could later be garbage collected, it would keep it in memory. The functions you're creating there are "closures" over the context, and so they keep it around.

But it's not a *leak*. If the element that `btnItem` refers to is removed, or its `firstChild` element is removed, then the event handlers no longer have anything referencing them, and so they become eligible for GC — whereupon, anything they're keeping in memory is eligible for GC.

There were issues with Internet Explorer not successfully cleaning things up in some situations, but I don't think this would have triggered the problem, and in any case I believe IE9+ handle those situations correctly.

> Not reffering to the outerscope variable will solve the problem?

*In theory*, it doesn't matter whether those functions refer to `btnItem` or not, they keep the execution context in memory.

*In practice*, JavaScript engines are allowed to optimize things as long as the optimization doesn't have observable side-effects other than reduced memory consumption and such. And so modern engines are smart about "optimizing" the closure and not keeping things around unnecessarily. They aren't perfect about it, but as long as your code isn't using `eval` or `new Function` (and your code isn't), the engine can usually optimize simple cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am confused with [mdn 2 example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Memory_leaks) and your r answer. As per mdn it will leads to memory leaks. can you please clarify the same?

Comment: It will lead to a memory leak **in Internet Explorer**. That is a browser bug and should not be the concern of website developers.

Comment: @Siguza, In this case I am not using it for a web-site instead for a framework.

Comment: @user3620283: Right, it's that circular reference that old versions of IE had issues with. It's not an issue in modern versions of IE, or in other browsers.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to avoid memory leak in this cae

Comment: @user3620283: If you remove the element (directly or indirectly), remove the handler from it explicitly. That breaks the circular reference, allowing the element and the handler to be garbage-collected.